# Standard action of SU(3) on $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

It is my understanding that SU(3) acts on $\mathbb{C}^3$  the same way SO(3) acts on $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. as proper rotations.

If this is the case, then the orbit of $(1,0,0) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ should be the unit sphere, i.e. vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$ with norm $1$. However this is wrong according to my teacher who says $M$, defined as $(z_1, z_2,z_3)$ with $\sum z_i^2 =1$ is not an orbit of SU(3).

The orbit is definitely contained in unit normed vectors as $v^\dagger v = v^\dagger U^\dagger U v = (Uv)^\dagger (Uv)$. However, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help see why $(1,0,0)$ cannot be mapped to all vectors of the  $(z_1, z_2,z_3)$ with $\sum z_i^2 =1$ using $SU(3)$. Also, what is the isotropy group in this case? I would think it's the SU(2) subgroup rotating orthogonally to $(1,0,0)$, i.e. matrices of the form

$$
C=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & U 
\end{array}\right]
$$

where U is in SU(2).

My guess is that somehow, we escape the subspace $M$, because she then asks about SO(3)'s action on it. With SO(3), we can think of a matrix acting on the real vector sum $(\bar x+i \bar y)$, and thus the norm of $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ are preserved, which leads to the complex norm being preserved, i.e. $\sum z_i^2 =1$.

Comment: $SU(3)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere $S$ of $\Bbb C^3$, but $$S=\left\lbrace\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb C^3\left|\right. |x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2=1\right\rbrace$$ (You forgot (typo?) the modules!)

Comment: Now I'm wondering if that's the trick my teacher was going for...so it does act transitively on the sphere as you've defined it. But the object $M$ she has given, is not the unit sphere because she is talking about literally squaring the complex numbers $z_i$ that make up the vector....that seems silly/tricky of her.

Comment: That isn't a sphere! It's a noncompact subset of $\Bbb C^3$!

Comment: Wait, which one isn't a sphere? The one I've given without the modulus?

Comment: Yes. The one without the modulus symbols is not a sphere because it's not a bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ (and hence noncompact as @TedShifrin mentioned).